# Android Get child items in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter for listView which has checkbox inside.
When checkbox value is changed, I want to get the list of items with checked checkboxies.

inside `onCreate` function for my activity

```
ArrayAdapter<DrawerDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DrawerDetail>(this, R.layout.settings_minidrawer_item, apps) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.settings_minidrawer_item, null);
        }
        ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
        appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);
        appIcon.setTag(apps.get(position).name);
        TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
        appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);
        appLabel.setText(Integer.toString(position));
        CheckBox appCheck = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_check);
        appCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                UpdatePreferences();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
};

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`updatePreferences`

```
public void UpdatePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();

    SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

    List<String> drawerListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    View v;
    CheckBox c;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, list);
        c = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_app_check);
        TextView aka = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
        aka.setText("dd");
        Log.e("checked: ", Boolean.toString(c.isChecked()));
    }
}
```

if you check `SparsBooleanArray checked` value, it is always null. Also `list.getAdapter().getView()` does not seem to be working.

this lines cannot find any view (does not return error, but cannot get/set value):

```
c = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_app_check);
TextView aka = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
```

I have tried different aproaches but could not make it work. Now My guess is that I am overriding `getView` method for adapter and they conflict with each other, but I could not come up with any soltuion how to override getView in a way that it will work for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't retrieve these views. Pass checked/unchecked information in your onCheckedChangeListener - e.g. String and info if it is checked/unchecked. Then you can collect checked items in array.

Try to do something like that:

```
public class TestClass {

    private List<String> checkedStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    void updateArray(boolean checked, String checkedText){
        if(checked){
            if(!checkedStrings.contains(checkedText)){
                checkedStrings.add(checkedText);
            }
        } else {
            checkedStrings.remove(checkedText);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your ArrayAdapter:

```
appCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                updateArray(isChecked, apps.get(position).label);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes but in my case I need to get all checked values not only the one I just checked. my approach seems to be incorect. I am new to android

Comment: Yes, I understand - you can create an array in a class, and put/remove checked/unchecked items into this array in UpdatePreferences method, when onCheckedChange is called. Do you want also update corresponding listview row, e.g. change it's title?

Comment: no just a list of checkboxes that are checked, but I should be able to get a tag from this checkbox. What do you mean create array in class?

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing your code :

```
c = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_app_check);
```

with this code :

```
View nextChild = null;

// Find CheckBox inside the parent view
for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    nextChild = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(i);
    if (nextChild instanceof CheckBox) {
        // Do your work;

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: why it cannot be found directly?

Comment: Because you're trying to access a view that belongs to the adapter class from another class (TestClass in your case). So if you were trying to access it from within the adapter class, you would just call it like you did (by id).